# Space anime with super large spaceship, lonely cube AI and young girl crowned as its queen

Tags: story-identification, anime, space, artificial-intelligence

So, someone is looking for a specific space anime and I want to help him.

His description of it:
https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/looking-for-a-specific-space-anime-pls-help.869977/

> so i'm looking for this very specific space anime i used to watch during my childhood. idk if it was good or popular, i just remember watching it.
>
> it's set in outer space (duh), where a colony lives in this floating city (idk, i just don't think there was a planet). it's focused on this young girl. she's going through her daily life on this space station thingo and one of her actions leads her contacting... a super space ship. idk what it was called exactly but here's what it boiled down to: a super fucking large space ship, with a super fucking massive city, with a super fucking lonely AI. The girl accidentally contacts the AI, idk if it was through space text chat or she accidentally stumbles upon the space ship itself.
>
> the AI/computer gets super attached to the girl, ofc. so there's a couple of episodes of wacky adventures between them. the AI has crowned the girl the 'queen' (I specifically remember that word being used) so like there's episodes when the girl is complaining to the AI about a jerk she met and the AI almost annihilates him blah blah blah. Then it gets... dark, i think? not sure if this is the same anime or i accidentally got it mixed up with another space anime (i did watch everything my dad downloaded then, so like... not impossible). anyway, it slowly becomes apparent the girl has some super fucking terrifying power because she's the super spaceship's queen. side note: it has the capabilities to house like, thousands, but the only living thing on the spaceship is the AI. i remember some long distant shots of the empty cities. i think the girl's colony gets attacked i think? there's a lot of running around. maybe another super spaceship turns up and challenges the AI. there's one super vivid shot of the girl finding this escape pod. its all fogged up so you can't see anything inside. she gets closer and then BAM! there's a bloody handprint on the glass. it's like, the scientist, or something?
>
> now that i'm thinking about it again, i think there's something to do with boxes and having all the people in the girl's colony in them????????
>
> i can't clearly remember it, because i was so young. I'm like 90% sure this is all one anime, but I might've mixed a couple of space-themed anime together.

> it was definitely an anime. it was one of those that had either 12 or 24 episodes.
> i don't know the year it was made. i could've watched it anywhere between 2007ish-2012ish. the style was quite old, compared to today's styles (not quite sailor moon but also not like, naruto/bleach style) and it was already completed when I watched it. if there were sequels then I've never watched them/heard of them.
>
> another thing i remember is the AI robot was in the shape of a cube, with an eye at one of the corners. it had little gremlin hands.

Comment: So is all of the text under the link the original poster's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So someone found it for me: *[Sora wo Kakeru Shoujo](https://myanimelist.net/anime/5307/Sora_wo_Kakeru_Shoujo)*

I haven't seen it yet, but finally can help the guy who asked it.
Hopefully you like it, too!

Synopsis:

> The story is set in the year 311 of the Orbital Calendar, when humanity has migrated to countless colony clusters in space. A space colony girl named Akiha Shishidou encounters a malevolent artificial intelligence named Leopard that has been installed on a colony.
>
> Akiha is joined by an Inter-Colony Police officer named Itsuki Kannagi, a taciturn young girl named Honoka Kawai, and a robot named Imoko "Imo-chan" Shishidou.

Comment: Would you be able to receive your own bounty if you answered your own question?

Comment: No you cant give the bounty back to yourself!